# I have a repeater and a dropdownlist inside this repeater

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater, sender, itemdatabound

I am populating dropdownlist inside a repeater (DropDownList is filled with values from database)

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                string idAdvert = objAdvert.GetAllIlanPage(ClsSession.idUser, null).Rows[i]["ID_ADVERT"].ToString();
                DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
                DDL.Items.Add("");
                DDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("Doping", idAdvert));
                DDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("İşlem", idAdvert));
                DDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
                i = i + 1;

            }
        }
```

It is working but when I click Dropdownlist, selectedindexchanged doesnt work. It always sends selectedIndex=1

```
 protected void SelectedIndex_Degisti(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
        //DropDownList doldurulacak_ddl = (DropDownList)ddl.Parent.FindControl("DropDownList1"); 
        ////Aynı satırdaki doldurulacak diğer droplisti bulduk.

        Control parent = ((Control)sender).Parent;
        DropDownList GeneralDDL = (DropDownList)parent.FindControl("DropDownList1");

        if (GeneralDDL.SelectedItem.Text == "Doping") ;//Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        else if (GeneralDDL.SelectedItem.Text == "İşlem") ;// Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding controls to the Repeater dynamically, you must make sure that you are re-adding these on *each PostBack*. This will enable the from values to be set to what the user chose.

Try moving your `Repeater.DataBind()` call to the `OnInit()` event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I solve the problem.
When I populate the DropDownList, I had given same value "Doping" and "Islem". It makes some confusion. So I put hiddenfield and I solve my problem.